# AngularUI element inside tab not accepting height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to add dynamic height for the element which is inside the tabset element Here is the plunker which describes the issue
http://plnkr.co/edit/IoBIkV0spK7mxPuK6As7?p=preview

I am trying to set the height for the div with id test
any help would be appreciated

HTML:

```
<tabset class="Tab">
    <tab class="tab1" heading="Static title1">
      <div style='border:1px solid #000;margin-top:15px;' id='test'>Test</div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Static title2">Static content2</tab>
    <tab heading="Static title3">Static content3</tab>
  </tabset>
```

Javascript

```
$('#test').css('min-height',($(window).height()-350)+'px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS, you don't manipulate the DOM in a controller.  You do that with a directive.  AngularJS has lots of a built-in directives that you can use to manipulate the DOM, one of which is ngStyle.  Of course, you can also create your own directives.

For these examples, you don't *need* jQuery since it's quite simple manipulate the styles with Javascript. But, if you need support for IE8 (which doesn't use window.innerHeight but instead uses document.documentElement.clientHeight) and want to simplify your code, or you're just not comfortable with Javascript, then you can use jQuery in your controller or directive to do your calculation (not to apply the style).

So if you wanted to just use the built in ngStyle directive, you pass it an object, such as:

```
<div style='border:1px solid #000;margin-top:15px;' ng-style="height" id="test">Test</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.height = {'min-height': window.innerHeight-350+'px'};
});
```

If you wanted to do something more sophisticated, you would create your own directive.  Here's an example:

```
app.directive('setHeight', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var h = window.innerHeight-350;
      element[0].style.minHeight = h+'px';
    }
  }
});
```

And you would use it in your markup like this:

```
<div style='border:1px solid #000;margin-top:15px;' id="test" set-height>Test</div>
```